# Can we create a trigger (or any object) to catch each login name

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2016

Actually I need to find all the users logged into a SQL Server in last month, so that I can delete the users which are not using SQL Server from AD group.

I was not able to find that so now I am trying to create trigger so that after one month I can delete users.

Comment: sql logon trigger is not allowing data reader user to login.

I am able to login to sql server as I am db owner But other users are who are added in data reader role are getting error while login.

I want that Logon trigger should allow to login for data reader users.

is there any trigger modification available to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Under the server properties select the Security tab and enable Login auditing for "Both failed and successful logins". The information is then recorded in the SQL Server Logs.

It is also possible to do it via trigger. Something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER Logon_Audit
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
   declare @acct as nvarchar(max)
   set @acct = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()

   -- insert @acct into some table
END
```

Comment: Very important note this needs: if you have a Logon Trigger, and the trigger errors (for whatever reason) and the error is *not* handled gracefully the login will fail. Logon triggers should be used *very* carefully; especially if they are performing DDL and DML operations.

Comment: After creating trigger,I tried to login then I am getting below error

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Logon failed for login 'loginname' due to trigger execution.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 17892)

Comment: thanks I used full qualified name for table and issue has been resolved now

Comment: sql logon trigger is not allowing data reader user to login. I am able to login to sql server as I am db owner But other users are who are added in data reader role are getting error while login. I want that Logon trigger should allow to login for data reader users. is there any trigger modification available to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I used fully qualified name for table and deleted multiple records

```
Create Table LoginDetails (iD int identity(1,1),LoginName nvarchar(max) , LoginTime datetime)

Create TRIGGER Logon_Audit
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
   declare @acct as nvarchar(max) 
   declare @LoginTime as nvarchar(max)
   set @acct = ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
   set @LoginTime = getdate() 

   insert into master..LoginDetails
   Select top 1 @acct,@LoginTime

   delete
   from  master..LoginDetails
   where id not in  (

                    Select max(id)
                    from LoginDetails
                    group by LoginName,LoginTime
                      )

END
```